# Create CSV file with UTF-8 encoding - PHP

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I'm creating csv file with UTF-8 encoding using PHP code, when i use UTF-8 encode it prints special characters not correctly,

Code :

```
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF)); // encode to UTF8
fputcsv($fp,$row,';',chr(0));


  rewind($fp);
                 Yii::app()->user->setState('export',stream_get_contents($fp));
                 fclose($fp);
                 Yii::app()->request->sendFile($name.'.csv',Yii::app()->user->getState('export'));
                 Yii::app()->user->clearState('export');
```

when i use `fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));` this the file is in UTF-8 encode but special characters are wrongly displayed `Honor� de Balzac 45100 Orl�ans`.

Please anyone provide me an idea to resolve this case

Comment: Ist your script utf8-encoded? Just an idea.

Comment: How are you trying to display the generated file?

Comment: @MarkBaker yess

Comment: Interesting answer to my question... I'm not familiar with a file viewer called yess; does it support UTF-8?

Comment: Despite your comment, printing `0xEFBBBF` does nothing to set or change the encoding of your data, it's merely an *indication* the spreadsheet software can choose to use. If `$row` is e.g. `Windows-1252` you'll end up with `Windows-1252` incorrectly advertised to be UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkBaker i am generating csv file, CSV file should be UTf-8 not with UTF8-BOM

Comment: Then ensure that all the data you write to the csv is utf-8 before writing it; and don't write the BOM... simply writing a BOM to a file doesn't do anything magical for subsequent writes

Comment: but my client wants file to in UTF8 encode

Comment: In fact, it really doesn't matter how badly your client and you want it, or how strong you wish it: your byte stream in some arbitrary/unknown encoding is not going to become UTF-8 for the sake of it. You can try adding more "file has to be UTF-8" comments but the result will be the same. /// Since this is getting nowhere, I'm closing with a hopefully useful duplicate.